# Rounded corners of windows

Tags: gnome-shell, appearance

I know that this feature is already in Ubuntu since few version but I didn't saw it in any version of Ubuntu. I'm using regular Ambience window style but I can't set rounded corners. All windows look like this: [image: nautilus window]

How make rounded corners?

Comment: Important: what version of Ubuntu are you using. 18.04 is using gnome 3. Gnome 3 has a lot less features than Unity (which got abandoned).

Comment: I don't know why you mentioned about Unity. I'm writing about Gnome3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had file that overwrites settings from theme. It was in `/home/user/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. When I deleted this file square corners disappear without any action (reboot or relogin). I don't know what created this file but I'm using the same profile for 10 years.